# Scrapping data with puppeteer in Nodejs, Results are different

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, xpath, puppeteer

I want to scrap the text '1 views' from this URL "https://www.loom.com/share/5b920dc1375f43fa9b622ac0a6ba7c52"
Url of image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgx6c.jpg

In browser console it gives result perfectly
Url of image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpHi2.jpg

but in puppeteer it gives 'Record a loom'
Url of image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFxRX.jpg

Comment: Don't use `innerText`, use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead.

Comment: last screenshort, line # 12, same result

Comment: Please also replace all images with text-based [mcve]s.

Comment: I will surely but i cant post images, edit question or ask a new question since there is some sort of limitation.

Comment: You should definitely be able to edit your own question. Also I'm asked to remove the images, not post more.

Comment: no option yet, it says u need 10 points for basic privileges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed a similar issue when trying different browsers. Your selector worked fine for me in Firefox, but not in Chrome. I'm assuming you are using Chrome with Puppeteer, as it is the default. If that's the case we are likely seeing the same issue. Anyway, try this selector out instead:

```
document.querySelector(`[class*="header-content"] span:nth-child(2)`)
```

Happy scraping, and cheers!

Comment: the selector works fine in browser but in code it gives "Null".

Comment: my xpath query was giving expected result on all browsers except chrome, but your selector gives same result on all browser so upvote for that :) cant do it pratically as i dont have that privilege yet

Comment: No worries, happy to help. This site has helped me over the years, so I figured it was time to start giving back. Yeah, Chrome displays a floating element in the bottom left corner which seemed to be the issue. With either query method, as long as you target the header area first, you should be able to navigate using the nth-child() method, class-based selector, or however that works in xpath. I'm a bit out of practice with xpath queries ;)